# Use of undeclared type 'Moment' in CalendarView

Tags: ios, swift, calendarview

I have installed CalendarView pod for calendar but months are not showing and when I've implemented this functions I am getting error on "moment" that use of undeclared type "Moment".

I want to change background of selected date as well as I want to set its a image instead of color and please help me to solve this undeclared issue.

```
var date: Moment! {
        didSet {
            title = date.format("MMMM d, yyyy")
        }
    }
extension ViewController: CalendarViewDelegate {

    func calendarDidSelectDate(date: Moment) {
        self.date = date
    }

    func calendarDidPageToDate(date: Moment) {
        self.date = date
    }
```

Comment: the Moment type doesnt exist as it said, try option click it and see if it lead to anything, or you forgot to import the module?

Comment: Try to build the project. I have faced same issue with Almofire and after building the error goes away.